# Android sqlite: order by to sort international characters

Tags: sorting, android, sqlite

I have a android database and it has a column called 'name'.'Name' column can have international characters. Now when I query this database, I want to sort the name column. The sort should consider international characters while sorting. I have read that there is a UNICODE collator for android but I am not able to use it in queries. Anybody has an idea how to use UNICODE collator. Can I really use UNICODE collator for sorting ? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Try these:

```
SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY name COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY name COLLATE UNICODE
```